# Troubleshoot local printer with journalctl command with elevated privileges

Tags: command-line, sudo, su

Since root passwd is disabled i can't invoke su -c 'journalctl -u cups.service --since="None" --until="2018-07-03"' > troubleshoot-logs.txt I'm looking for sudo analogue

Comment: `sudo journalctl -u cups.service --since="None" --until="2018-07-03"`?

Comment: OK at least it works, thanks,  but a period still limited by choose of --since or --until and not by two edges.

Comment: which seems to be a different problem. You can edit the question to reflect the new problem if you want.